Using webauthn and passwords in sandboxed iframe
If an iframe doesn’t allow same-origin, then requests to servers and postMessage to other windows are treated as cross-origin.
But what about interaction with the browser? Say an iframe is loaded from twitter.com without allowing same-origin
Will webauthn work with it, using twitter.com credentials?
How about PaymentRequest?
How about Password autofills?
Would like the answers to specify browsers (eg Chrome, iOS Safari etc.) I understand that cross-origin iframes cannot create credentials in browsers yet (despite the latest webauthn spec) and I am not asking about that.

My experience is browsers are getting stricter and stricter about this, so even if you find something that works today, it’s unlikely to work in the future.
